# Redirection doesnt work properly

Tags: php, html

I was trying to redirect an html page to two different php files. 
Html file which i created is `redirect.html`. When i go to that page it would check if i was logged in or not, if i was not it would take me to `ucplogin.php`
on the other hand if i was logged in it'd take me to `ucphome.php`.
Here the problem is the code i'm trying is obviously messed up because i've been trying for a while and still doesnt work

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com">
        <script type="text/javascript">


            <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['playername']))
            {
            ?>
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/working/ucplogin.php"
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            window.location.href = "http://localhost/working/ucphome.php"
            <?php
            }
            ?>

        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I have seen all those answers and got some points but i rewrite the code to this

```
 <?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['playername']))
    {
    ?>
    header('Location: http://localhost/working/ucplogin.php');
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    header('Location: http://localhost/working/ucphome.php');
    <?php
    }
?>
```

when i go to redirect.php it gives me header('Location: http://localhost/working/ucphome.php');  when i'm logged in and this when i'm not `header('Location: http://localhost/working/ucplogin.php');`

Apparently it works but technically not, it doesn't redirect me to the exact page.

Comment: you write php in a .html file??? it isn't acceptable

Comment: @Peyman.H sure it is. If instructing Apache to treat them as PHP, why not? edit: you even wrote it in your answer.

Comment: You embed PHP in JavaScript. This is not possible! You can echo JavaScript with PHP, e.g. echo `<script>window.location.href=....</script>`.

Comment: I edited the code and now it works but technically not,

Answer (score 1):

> > Html file which i created is redirect.html

You cannot run PHP code in a plain HTML file, unless you instruct Apache to run HTML files as PHP (Thanks to @Fred -ii- for pointing this out. Also see @Peyman.H answer for how to do this). The reason the `php` extension exists is to tell the server there is PHP code that needs to be processed. Rename the extension to `.php` and you will be good.

Additionally, what if the user has JavaScript disabled? It is safer to use the PHP function [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for your redirects instead:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['playername'])) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/working/ucplogin.php');
} // etc...
```

Comment: *"You cannot run PHP code in a plain HTML file."* - that's not entirely true. You can if instructing Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Comment: but header is not working in my code, it just show the line in the page when i go to redirect.php, i have edited the code above,,

Comment: No, header is a _PHP_ function, you need to place that code in your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use in your file a JavaScript code by just typing the following

```
  <script>
window.location="redirect.php" ;
    </script>
```